# How to use $(this) with jquery to change an element that is on the parent of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a simple thing with JQuery but I struggle to understand what I should do.

What I'd like to do is when `.overlay-detail` is hovered `$(this).closest('p img:first-child').css('display', 'none')` else `('display', 'block')`

(see html to understand)

```
<div id="block-views-quipe-block">

<div class="field-content">
   <p>
     <img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/_CA17330lr.jpg">
     <img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/_CA17322lr.jpg">
   </p>

   <div class="overlay-detail">
     <p>John Doe 1</p>
     <p>job 1</p>
   </div>
</div>  

<div class="field-content">
   <p>
     <img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/_CA17330lr.jpg">
     <img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/_CA17322lr.jpg">
   </p>

   <div class="overlay-detail">
     <p>John Doe 2</p>
     <p>job 2</p>
   </div>
</div>  

...

</div>
```

Here is what I thought doing :

```
$("#block-views-quipe-block .overlay-detail").hover(function(){
  $(this).closest('p img:first-child').css("display", "none");
}, function(){
   $(this).closest('p img:nth-child(2)').css("display", "block");
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: closest() only searches ancestors and keeps going up until finds a match, so rather try using parent().find() here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because `closest()` looks for parent elements, whereas the `p` is a sibling. Use `prev()` instead to get the `p`, then `find()` to get the child `img`:

```
$("#block-views-quipe-block .overlay-detail").hover(function(){
  $(this).prev('p').find('img:first-child').hide();
}, function(){
  $(this).prev('p').find('img:nth-child(2)').show();
});
```